# Do pull request accept future commits from the source branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I create a pull request from one branch to other at some point and then I do some commits to source branch before merge. After the pull request is merged. Is that merge includes the commits which I have done after the pull request but before merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just push the commits to the source branch you have created Pull Request (PR will be updated automatically). You can see the Commit lists in `Pull Requests` | `Commits` section.

Answer (score 1):

Pull request will accept future commit in the source branch, you can even pull data from server even before commit or after commit.

**Auto Merging** will take place when you pull after commit, so there is no issues about .